# Etiqueta [W3C], ¿la gran olvidada?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Tengo la necesidad de preguntar **¿por qué no existe la etiqueta [w3c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c)** para temas relacionados con la estandarización, semántica y uso correcto de los temas, elementos, metas y demás recursos validados por el Consorcio WWW?

Es **importante** no solo resolver dudas relacionadas con un problema, sino también el solventar la duda de lo *políticamente correcto* para la W3C.

Las **ventajas** que podría conllevar la creación de la etiqueta [w3c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) sería la **extrapolación de los principales lenguajes web**, reuniendo en una sola etiqueta todas las dudas basadas en estandarización.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un caso concreto en el que se usaría la etiqueta [tag:w3c]? En la mayoría de los supuestos que pones, parece que sería suficiente con la etiqueta del lenguaje, siendo w3c más una meta-etiqueta (que no se deberían usar) que algo que identifique/proporcione información sobre la pregunta.

Comment: Un caso concreto puede ser la existencia de una pregunta que pida resolver la estructura semántica en tres lenguajes, HTML, Javascript y CSS. En vez de añadir tres etiquetas, una bastaría para agrupar el contenido de la duda sobre estandarización, dejando las otras tres para preguntas relacionadas sobre problemas sintácticos en sí.

Comment: No termino de verlo. Teniendo en cuenta que el W3C es una organización, la etiqueta [tag:w3c] no aportaría realmente nada en ese caso, y sería mejor usar [tag:estandarización] o [tag:desarrollo-web] o [tag:estructura-web]. Si en el futuro el W3C no se encarga del estándar web, habría que cambiar todas las preguntas etiquetadas con eso, porque la etiqueta dejaría de tener sentido.

Answer (score 7):

La razón de que no exista es, básicamente, que nadie la ha utilizado.

Las etiquetas pueden ser creadas por cualquier usuario a partir de 300 de reputación, como se explica en la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), por lo que si tienes que hacer una pregunta que necesite la etiqueta [w3c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) tu mismo puedes crearla.

Debes tener en cuenta que como se explica en la página de ayuda:

> En algunos sitios, las nuevas etiquetas se eliminarán automáticamente del sistema si no se utilizan por lo menos en 1 pregunta más en un período de 6 meses.

También es importante el punto siguiente:

> ¿Cuándo debo crear una nueva etiqueta?
>
> Las etiquetas más comunes ya existen en un sitio maduro. Siempre debes favorecer las etiquetas existentes. Sólo crea nuevas etiquetas cuando sientas que puedes argumentar que tu pregunta cubre un nuevo tema que nadie más ha preguntado antes en este sitio.

Por último, personalmente no estoy muy seguro de la necesidad de dicha etiqueta. En SO existe, pero sólo con 1120 preguntas, que para el número de preguntas de un sitio tan enorme me parece casi residual.

Comment: Puedo imaginar que si hay solo 1120 preguntas con la etiqueta w3c en SO es porque las personas que preguntan sobre cual es la manera correcta de escribir equis cosa en HTML, Javascript o CSS, no conocen de la existencia de la W3C. Resulta lógico a mi parecer. El mismo caso podemos traspasarlo a SO en español, pero a menor escala.